# JS - Multiplicar e Mostrar em texto

Tags: javascript

Ola,

Eu gostaria de criar um código que fizesse uma multiplicação doque o Cliente inserise no Campo Input text.

Esta multiplicaçao seria...

```
Valor de taxa = 0.8;
Valor do Cliente = "O valor inserido"

Valor do Cliente * Valor de taxa.
```

Gostaria que aparecesse em texto... Como faço?

JAVASCRIPT

```
function calculate() {

var coins = document.getElementById('number').value;
var rate = 0.8;
var total = coins * rate;

}
```

Comment: O que você já sabe de JS? Sabe como buscar os valores de um campo do HTML? Ou não terá a interface HTML neste problema? Onde exatamente está com dificuldade?

Comment: dificuldade esta em criar o script javascript para que apareça em texto quando o cliente inserir um numbero. Poderia ajudar?

Comment: E como será lido esse número do usuário?

Comment: O numero do usuario sera Lido pelo INPUT TYPE = TEXT

Comment: Então, perguntando novamente, você já sabe como buscar o valor de um `input` HTML com JS? Se sim, mostre que você já desenvolveu alguma coisa e adicione o código à pergunta. Aliás, busque fazer um [mcve] mostrando o que pretende fazer.

Comment: eu já fiz a funçao javascript mas quero que automaticamente pareça em texto logo quando o cliente poem 1 numero... ele vai calculando simplesmente, vou por codigo acima.

Answer (score 1):

Através desse exemplo `Jquery` você pode adequar as suas necessidades:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.mask/1.14.15/jquery.mask.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="valor_do_cliente">
<span id="resultado">0</span>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var taxa = 0.8;
    $('#valor_do_cliente').keyup(function(){
        var valor = $('#valor_do_cliente').val();
        var resultado = Math.ceil(valor * taxa);
        $('#resultado').html(resultado);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: amigo não é isso que procuro, procuro quando inseres um numero, ele digita logo em TEXTO ou DIV o valor ja calculado. Sem ser necessário Submeter

Comment: prontinho amigo, resposta editada de acordo com sua necessidade

Comment: Ok.. e se o input tiver vazio.. como faço para ele ficar 0 no texto?

Comment: Assim como na edição que fiz, vc pode deixar um `0` onde vai imprimir o resultado, assim, uma vez que for digitando vai alterando

Comment: ok.. desta maneira está otimo e agradeco, mas só mais 1 coisa. Ele está em decimal.. como aredondo exemplo.. Cliente poem 1 ele fica 0.8... arredondando ficaria 1 ....?

Comment: Já esta editado de acordo. Se for a reposta que procurava, por favor marque como resposta correta. Grato por poder ajudar

Answer (score 1):

Você pode ficar "assistindo" o seu input e sempre que ocorresse alguma alteração nele, dispararia a função com a lógica desejada!

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var input1 = $("#valor_unitario");
    var result = $("#result");
    
    $(input1).on("change keyup paste", function(){
      var resultado = $(input1).val() * 0.8;
      result.html(resultado);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="valor_unitario">Vlr. Unit.</label>
<input type="text" name="valor_unitario" id="valor_unitario" style="text-align: center" required>
<p>Resultado: <span id="result"></span></p>
```